# How tendency to revise is related to maintaining uniqueness of the work?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the following sentence:

> There has been a tendency among art historians not so much to revise as to eliminate the concept of the Renaissance - to contest not only its uniqueness, but its very existence.

How the tendency of not revising the work is related to not maintaining the uniqueness of the work?

If I don't revise or update my work, will that affect the uniqueness of my work?

I believe that, my consistency to do something unique affects the uniqueness of my work?

What is author actually trying to convey through the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence says that art historians have been not so much *revising the concept of the Renaissance* (changing the way they think about it), as *eliminating the concept* (deciding that the Renaissance didn't happen at all). This has nothing to do with revising a piece of work; it refers to revising their ideas about the Renaissance (or not, in this case).

*Uniqueness* refers to the Renaissance itself being unique, not a piece of work.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. But I have a question: If they eliminated the concept of renaissance, how can they revise it? If someone believes that a particular thing didn't happened, how can they change their way to think about it?

Comment: _Not so much... as..._ means that they have _not_ revised the concept, but  eliminated it. Sorry, my last comment was unintentionally misleading. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Exactly! as per my last question, what is author trying to say? How renaissance's uniqueness is affected by deciding hat the renaissance didn't happen at all ?

Comment: _The Renaissance_ (rebirth) is the name traditionally given to a period of cultural change in Europe during the 15th and 16th centuries. Apparently, art historians are now saying that there was nothing special, or unique, about this period, so therefore what we call 'the Renaissance' didn't actually happen.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now. Thanks for your contribution. Kindly keep doing the same as there are a lot of strugglers out there trying to understand and learn English